# How to use sum, replace, and case in the same setting?

Tags: sql

I have a table where numbers are stored as strings and some bigger numbers look like 1,634.5 so I have to replace the "," with blanks to get accurate data.

I have been using this which works, but I can't figure out how to do that with sum and case as I need to sum up the revenue together when it equals xyz

code that works

```
(replace(revenue, ',', '')
```

code that doesn't work

```
sum(replace(revenue, ',', '') case WHEN food in ('burgers', 'fries') then revenue else 0 end)) as  foodsum
group by foodcategory
```

i also tried using a nested query but didn't work, does anyone have any recommendations?

thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct way on aggregating your `revenue` based on `foodcategory`.

```
select case when food in ('burgers', 'fries') then sum(replace(revenue, ',', '')) else 0 end as foodsum
from table1
group by foodcategory
```